# Why is Graph an atomic expression in Mathematica?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, core-language, language-design

Actually, the title says it all. I am a little confused why such a complicated object as `Graph`, with many different parts, was designed to be atomic in Mathematica language such that, for example, function `Part` cannot be used on it.

Comment: And how do you suppose to use `Part` on `Graph`? There is a [`Subgraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subgraph.html) for subgraphs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question seems to be rhetorical -- merely a rant. It might be an acceptable question if it asked about extracting some property of a graph.

Comment: @m_goldberg Rhetorical questions do not require any answers, whereas I am genuinely interested in the reasons why introduced in version 8 object Graph was decided to be atomic.

Comment: @Artem right, but the only ones who can answer that are the developers of the `Graph` functions.  You could rephrase the question to be on topic.  What do you want to get out of a `Graph` by using `Part`?  You can get the vertices and edges through other means

Comment: I don't agree with closing. In MMA you can do whatever you want with expressions so if some of them get serious limitations there is clearly a reason. And while at the end only developers know, they are around as well as people who think alike and possibly have very plausible explanations. I'm not one of them but my guess is: may be that some of graph related functions are handled by low level code which requires a valid Graph structure one could destroy if they weren't atomic.

Comment: The question of why `Part` does not work on `Graph` is different from why it is atomic. Packed arrays are also atomic, but none of the functionality lets you see this. This is because they assume the interface to packed arrays (mainly `Part` and `Extract` and arithmetic operations with other packed arrays) to remain stable. However, I think it would be foolish to pretend `Graph` is also just an ordinary expression with `Part`s that can be `Extract`ed. IMO this doesn't make sense for any data structure consisting of parts of different types of data.

Comment: @masterxilo Try `First@Plot[x, {x, -2, 2}]` - `Graphics` is not atomic, but its parts are of wildly different types.  I can understand the motivation for wanting `Graph` to be non-atomic, I have often wished to get the coordinates list from a `MeshRegion` using `First`.  But I can get all the data I need from a `MeshRegion` using `MeshCoordinates`, `MeshPrimitives`, `MeshCells`, etc.

Comment: Likewise, you can access many parts of a `Graph` using built in functions, like `VertexList`, `GraphEmbedding`, etc.  So if there is a particular property of a `Graph` that OP can't access, then **that** would be an on-topic question, IMO.

Comment: @JasonB The question is not about the functionality but about the underlying principles of Mathematica. Say, when I am teaching any math course, I can give very convincing reasons why we choose one or another definition. Now, if I teach Mathematica course and introduce atomic expressions, it is an extremely natural question to ask why, along with numbers, symbols and strings, Graphs are atomic. And I have no idea what to answer to such a question.

Answer (score 11):

`Graph` may be atomic to allow an optimized internal form. Graph operations are often computationally intensive and it makes sense to keep `Graph` data in a form that can be operated upon quickly, perhaps by external libraries, without the overhead of converting from a plain *Mathematica* expression every time.  This is the case with `Image` I believe, which also is atomic.

Comment: Thank you, but do not you think that similar explanation would work for many other objects (say, RandomFunction), which, however, are not atomic?

Comment: @Artem by `RandomFunction` do you mean the `TemporalData` expression it returns?  If so I believe most of the processing that is done on `TemporalData` expressions is top-level *Mathematica* code, not C library level as I *think* a fair amount of the `Graph` functionality is.

Answer (score 10):

`Graph` being `AtomQ` has about the same implications as doing lots of overloadings of the type `Part[_Graph,___] := Error[]; Replace[_Graph,___] := Error[]; ...`. It signifies that it is an "[abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type)" whose API (in the form of functions like `VertexList`) shall be the only way to interface with its contents. It would actually be nice to be able to do this type of thing automatically for user-defined "types" (heads of data structures), to ensure no-one relies on the current representation of the data as an expression.

Things are `AtomQ` for the same reason as internal data is declared `private` in the OO-world: [Information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).

Comment: Following the logic of Artem's comment under my answer above if this were the primary reason I would expect a number of other expressions like `TemportalData`, `InterpolatingFunction`, and `TimeSeries` to also be atomic as these have API's of this sort as well, but these are not atomic.  Perhaps this is nothing more than inconsistency but I favor a different explanation.