# Why is SparseArray atomic?

Tags: replacement, sparse-arrays, language-design

[This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/using-replaceall-on-sparsearray#13792) tells us that functions like `ReplaceAll` do not straightforwardly work for the entries of sparse arrays because a `SparseArray` is an atomic object (though see the comments to [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/468500/29926)...?). As I find it a bit annoying and inelegant to have to do something like

```
SparseArray[ArrayRules @ # /. replacementrules, Dimensions @ #] &
```

when I want to use `ReplaceAll` on the entries of a sparse array I was wondering why one would want `SparseArray` (and similar functions) to be atomic in the first place: what are the benefits? In particular, if it is possible, I would like to see some practical examples of such benefits.

Comment: [108948](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108948/5478), [Why is Graph an atomic expression in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127522/5478), are those topics exhausting this one?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks, that is indeed a relevant and rather similar question. But if it is possible I would like to see some practical examples of benefits -- I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: It's atomic so that the internal implementation can be very efficient and can be swapped out for an even more efficient one in the future, if needed. But you are asking the wrong question. You should be asking: why doesn't `ReplaceAll` support sparse arrays directly?  In principle there is nothing preventing Wolfram from adding this feature. In practice, "atomic" means that there are no guarantees about which structural operations work on the type. For example, both `SparseArray` and `Rational` can be decomposed by pattern matching (try `a_[b___]` on them), while other atoms can't.

Comment: The key benefit is you can't break internal procedures optimized for specific atomic object. Who knows what constraints they have.

Comment: This also shows you that `ReplaceAll` *does* work on `SparseArray`, but it does not treat it as a list. It treats it as if it had a specific compound (i.e. non-atomic) structure (that describes a [*compressed sparse row*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29) format).  We are exploiting this in [MATLink](http://matlink.org/) to retrieve the internal structure of sparse arrays and efficiently transfer them to/from MATLAB.

Comment: I think that if we start thinking about how `ReplaceAll` could work on a `SparseArray` and treat it as a list, it won't be hard to notice a number of difficulties ... for example, what would you expect `0 :> RandomReal[]` to do when `0` is the background value?  Replace each array element that is 0 separately, even though they are not explicitly stored? Replace the backgound value once? What if some of the explicit values are equal to the background value?

Comment: @Kuba "you can't break internal procedures optimized for specific atomic object" -- could you make this statement more explicit or give an example?

Comment: @JulesLamers no :) the key is 'internal'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ReplaceAll on SparseArray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/using-replaceall-on-sparsearray)