# Manipulate MeshRegion as normal Mathematica expression

Tags: expression-manipulation, mesh

A `MeshRegion` seems to function quite differently from any other Mathematica expression. One cannot take a `Part` of it. Nor can I simply exchange its head to something else using `Apply`. What is going on here and how do I extract the argument in some manipulable form?

Comment: `MeshRegion` is an [atomic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/list-of-atomic-expressions) expression. See also [AtomQ](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AtomQ.html)

Comment: @Pinti, thanks! That is really annoying though and there does not seem to be a good reason why it would need to be. If you look at the FullForm you see that it would be perfectly possible to select its arguments.

Comment: That's what you use `MeshCoordinates[]` and `MeshCells[]` for.

Comment: As for why `MeshRegion` is like this it is probably for similar reasons as for `Graph` which are discussed here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127522/why-is-graph-an-atomic-expression-in-mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

`MeshRegion` is an [atomic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46850/list-of-atomic-expressions) expression. This may be to allow an optimized internal form. See an explanation for why `Graph` is atomic in [Why is Graph an atomic expression in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/127522/45020). Parts can be taken using `MeshCoordinates[]`, `MeshCells[]` and `Options[]`. (I do not know whether these three functions can obtain all data contained in a MeshRegion but for now it seems like it.)

Another workaround would be to convert to a `String` and act on that:

```
takeArgumentMeshRegion[meshreg_]:=ToExpression@StringCases[ToString[FullForm@meshreg],"MeshRegion["~~x__~~"]":>"{"<>x<>"}"];
```

However, this might be a bad idea since there is a reason why Mathematica tries to keep us from taking arguments like this.